# Optimize Tables in Database Design

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, database-design

I have 3 tables Product, Color and Category. Color and category table has just name field. So I need to optimize number of tables. 
Because For retrieving data for product, I need to get data from all of these tables. Instead of it, I just want something like single table. So Everything can be retrieve from Single table.

**In short, Looking for way to adjust color and category name in product table with Dynamic Insert and update functionality.**

```
Product Table

product_id | int
name       | varchar
description| text
category   | cat_id
color      | color_id
size       | size_id

Color Table

color_id   | int
color      | varchar  

Category Table

cat_id     | int
category   | varchar
```

For retrieving data form Product table, I need to write `JOIN`, Because color and category have data for product table. and more Join query results more loading time. So need to optimize number of tables.

Comment: how many colors? how many categories?

Comment: They must be dynamic. Admin can Insert| Update|delete from backend.@etsa

Comment: Your schema looks reasonable to me.  What is your actual question?

Comment: I need to reduce number of tables. 3 tables to 1 table. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Why?  For (supposted) better performance or other?

Comment: @Dhruvang Doing so would mean denormalizing your schema, which would waste a lot of space.  To be clear here: there is nothing wrong with doing joins provided the database and query are tuned properly.

Comment: Yes, for better Performance @etsa

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is it not necessary to optimize loading speed and complexity of program to remove joins

Comment: See last comment of Tim above.    Unless you have a very high number of colors and categories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current structure is good enough to hold product information with single color and category. Right now there is no need to optimize table structure. It look like perfect database structure for this.

You can create view to avoid writing joins every time.

Comment: and you can (it depends...) have better performances creating indexes on product table (one with color_id and one with cat_id)